# Ball draw with condition

Tags: probability

I wanted to calculate probability of certain event. There are two collections of mixed together balls with numbers from 1-10 and 11-20. The problem is I need to pick two certain balls from first collection (1 and 2) and one from second collection (11). No putting them back, three drwas.
Condition is:

> collections are mixed until two balls from one group are chosen, then other collection is separated/removed so I chose only from population of 10 balls to pick third ball.

I tried to work with probability tree, there is possibility of drawing two balls from different groups, then third is picked from total population of 18 left. Second option two balls were chosen from population 1 (1-10) then third is picked from 10 remaining separated balls. Last one that is bad for me is two balls are picked from second population 11-20 which is losing for me, since I want only one from there.

Not sure if this can be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

There are three favorable cases: $\mathcal{112, 121, 211}$ representing the order of drawing from the two collections. The probability of the first case is $\frac{1}{20} \cdot \frac{1}{19} \cdot \frac{1}{10}\cdot 2$, of the second case is $\frac{1}{20} \cdot \frac{1}{19} \cdot \frac{1}{18} \cdot 2$, and of the third case happening is $\frac{1}{20} \cdot \frac{1}{19} \cdot \frac{1}{18} \cdot 2$

(notice the multiplication by $2$ to account for the order of drawing out balls $1,2$ from collection $\mathcal 1$)

The desired probability is then the sum of these individual probabilities.